# Flutter encrypt large files

Tags: flutter, encryption

I want to change the file's byte for encryption, but when i use readAsBytes() method for large file, i get out of memory error. So is there any way to encrypt large file with less memory consumption.
Thank you

Comment: yes, use `File.openRead`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you need a temporary buffer to hold your data. If your RAM is not large enough (very likely on mobile devices) it has to be the disk.

So create a second file, and read the first file in batches of bytes that are small enough your memory will be able to handle it. Your encryption method should be able to handle this, as it's a very common occurrence. Write the resulting batches of encrypted content to the second file. Once you are done, delete/overwrite the original.

Comment: Thank you both of you guys, but currently my issue is, when i get data from file.openRead(), the data return format is Stream<List<int>>. So when i want to get data List<int>, it's not return all of data. Just 65536 bytes i can get. So how can i get all data without lost data.

Comment: @MuhammedEmir *"but when i use readAsBytes() method for large file, i get out of memory error"* - so you want to get data in chunks or not?

Comment: @pskink Yes, for example for 1 GB file, i want to take 100 MB per loop and rewrite the file again. I tried this code, but for every loop i didn't take size of file what i want. 
  'for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfFile; i++) {
      await originalFile.openRead(i, i + pms).forEach((element) async {
        await newFile.writeAsBytes(element, mode: FileMode.append);
      });
    }
    await originalFile.openRead(sizeOfFile - lastData, sizeOfFile).forEach((event) async {
      await newFile.writeAsBytes(event, mode: FileMode.append);
    });'

Comment: *"Just 65536 bytes i can get. So how can i get all data without lost data"* - @MuhammedEmir what do you see if you call `openRead().forEach(e) => print(e.length))` ? do you see `65536` only once on the logs? or you see a lot of `65536` (or similar numbers)?

Comment: I see a lot 65536, and when i complete write file new file size only half size of original file. For 1 GB file i get like 500 MB size for new file

Comment: @MuhammedEmir so if you see a lot of them it means that the whole input file is read in 65536 byte chunks - if your output file is half size the error is in writing, not reading

Comment: Unfortunately it's not. Can you try for image file with my code which i sent you? Maybe my code is wrong

Comment: @pskink Not same but so near original file size, the issue is about writing file. Thank you very much for helping

Comment: @MuhammedEmir `var cnt = 0;
var mapper = (List<int> data) {
cnt += data.length;
print(cnt);
return data;
};
var output = File('output.mp4').openWrite();
await File(input)
.openRead()
.map(mapper)
.pipe(output);
print('finito!!! $cnt bytes read and written');`